# Connect table from Database file to python

Tags: python, sqlite

Can somebody help me with that code! So with the if clause I want to make the program to open the operator menu only if I log in with admin. By this way of the code it is an error: administrator is not defined. How can I fix that?

```
def operator_menu():
    print("Operator Menu")
    print("1. Show all bookings")
    print("2. Register a new driver")
    print("3. Remove a booking")
    print("4. View available drivers")
    print("5. Logout")

    menu_input = input("What would you like to do?: ")
    if menu_input == "1":
        show_bookings()
    if menu_input == "2":
        register_newdriver()
    if menu_input == "3":
        remove_booking()
    if menu_input == "4":
        available_drivers()
    if menu_input == "5":
        exit()
      


def show_bookings():
    if not(current_user == create_company(conn, administrator)):
        bookings = get_trips(conn)
        if not bookings:
            print("No bookings.")
        else:
            print("Available bookings:")
            for i, booking in enumerate(bookings):
                print(str(i)+". "+str(booking[4])+" -> "+str(booking[5]) + " -> "+str(booking[6])+ " - "+str(booking[7]))

        input("Press any key to continue...")
        operator_menu()
    else:
        driver_menu()

def create_company(conn,administrator):
    sql = ''' INSERT INTO administrator(name)
              VALUES(?) '''
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql,administrator)
    conn.commit()
    return cur.lastrowid
```

Comment: Isn't the error pretty clear? Where is `administrator` ever assigned? Or even `conn`? Please post fuller code for a [mcve] including all `import` lines.

Answer (score 0):

there are two possible situation here. one is you are trying to see if the loged in (windows) user is administrator, second is you are creating an application which has a login window, so there are two kind of users: application manager and other users.

if it's the first case then you can use subprocess module as below

```
import subprocess
current_user = subprocess.check_output("if %errorlevel% equ 0 (echo admin) else (echo limited)",shell=True).decode("utf-8").strip()
if current_user == 'admin':
    operator_menu()
else:
    user_menu()
```

if it's second case then I think this code can help you and easy to understand. you must have a table in your database by name users that stores user informations including a column determining privilages of loged in user. then you should retrieve user info from an existed tabled namely users. if you did not create this table, here is the code:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("example.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
sql = "create table if not exists users (username text, password text, privilages bool)"
cur.execute(sql)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

then you should retrieve user information from this table to see if user has privilages or not.

```
import sqlite3

def user_menu():
    pass#put some code here

def show_bookings():
    pass#put some code here

def register_newdriver():
    pass#put some code here

def remove_booking():
    pass#put some code here

def available_drivers():
    pass#put some code here

def operator_menu():
    while True:
        print("Operator Menu:")
        print(" 1. Show all bookings")
        print(" 2. Register a new driver")
        print(" 3. Remove a booking")
        print(" 4. View available drivers")
        print(" 5. Logout")

        menu_input = input("What would you like to do?: ")
        if menu_input == "1":
            show_bookings()
        elif menu_input == "2":
            register_newdriver()
        elif menu_input == "3":
            remove_booking()
        elif menu_input == "4":
            available_drivers()
        elif menu_input == "5":
            quit()
        else:
            print("invalid choice: ", menu_input)

# define some code that get username from login form. for example
username = miroslav
sql = '"select * from users where username="' + username + '"'
cur.execute(sql)
user_info = cur.fetchall()[0]
if user_info[3] == True:
    operator_menu()
else:
    user_menu()
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer!But I the idea is to be logged in admin and user.And If logged in by admin program open operator menu. When I login by the user to open user menu!With this code gave me error admin is not defined where is need to be defined.That you wrote me is complicate for me!Is there something simplyer?

Comment: Hi @MiroslavN. your question is a little bit vague. I updated the code and tried to answer it in both cases, unless there is a third possibility that I am not aware of. I did not test the code but I think you can fix the bugs easily. hope it does not contain any. good luck